# why I can't implement the decode function to string?

Tags: python, string, nltk, decode, tokenize

I'm researching a dataset and rerun my coworker's code. When tokenizing text data, the  code shown below doesn't work on my macbook, however, worked well in my coworker's computer.Here is the code.

I don't know which version does he have but mine is python3.6.
Is it the problem of different versions?

```
s=title+' '+author+' '+text
 tokens=word_tokenize(s.decode('ascii','ignore').lower())
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e50403f82604> in <module>
     10         flushPrint(m/100)#208
     11     s=title+' '+author+' '+text
---> 12     tokens=word_tokenize(s.decode('ascii','ignore').lower())
     13     tokens = [z for z in tokens if not z in stopset and len(z)>1]
     14     k=[]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Not sure about `word_tokenize` but `str` decode code works fine for me in Python2.7

Answer (score 3):

The issue is most probably due to the changes between python2 and python3

**In python2**

- `''` is of type `str` and thus supports `''.decode()`
- `u''` is of type `unicode` and thus supports `u''.encode()`

**In python3 this is reversed**

- `''` is of type `unicode` and thus supports `''.encode()`
- `u''` is of type `byte` and thus supports `u''.decode()`

So in your case, depending on the type of your variables you might have to do something like

```
s = title + b' ' + author + b' ' + text
```

of just resort to python 2 :)

Comment: the b' ' worked! Does it just transfer the str into a byte?

Comment: It just says to python3 "handle what's between the quotes as a byte-text" : Writing `b''` in py3 is the exact equivalent to writing `''` in py2. It just changed :/ 
You can read this if you want more details : https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html